# Excel 2013 DisplayAlerts False is still prompting for changes save upon quitting

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that does some calculations then it is supposed to close excel withOUT prompting to save any changes and withOUT saving.

Here is the code:

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ThisWorkbook.Saved = True
Application.Quit
```

This works fine on Excel 2010. On Excel 2013 (64 bit version), This is also working fine. However, My friend using Excel 2013(32 bit version..not sure if it makes a difference) and the Excel is prompting him to save changes before closing.

Is there a different code I should be using for 2013? Any idea?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Save changes pop up appears in case if your excel contains any volatile functions as such. This function gets updated on workbook open and hence at the time of closing save changes dialog box appears. To suppress this you can use following code and i hope this will work:

```
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ThisWorkbook.Saved = True
Application.Quit
```